# How can I move focus from the Quick Documentation pop-up back to the Code completion pop-up without using the mouse?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

**Context**:

When a code completion pop-up (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) appears I often need to have a look at docs for each individual method / constant / etc). The IDE is set to show the Quick Documentation pop-up for a highlighted suggestion automatically after a small delay. Sometimes the documentation is too big and I need to jump to the Quick Documentation pop-up in order to be able to scroll down through it.

Using the mouse I can click on the documentation pop-up and scroll using the mouse wheel. When I'm done reading the documents I can click on the code completion pop-up to explore other suggestions.

My problem is that once the Quick Documentation pop-up is in focus, I haven't found a way to move the focus back to the code completion pop-up without using the mouse.

While I can move focus from the code completion to the quick documentation pop-up by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, and then use the arrow keys to "scroll" through the documentation, I haven't found a shortcut to return the focus to the code completion pop-up.

What I've tried to far:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> closes both pop-ups
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> a second time opens the docs on a tool window

Any insights on how I can close the Quick Documentation pop-up or move the focus back to the code completion pop-up in such a way that preserves the suggestion that I have previously highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA . Feel free to add your use-case at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168388

Here is a workaround that could be used for the time being:

1. Open Documentation as a Tool Window:

   [image]
2. Add keyboard shortcut to focus documentation window from anywhere:

   [image]
3. When the completion popup appears, focus documentation tool window by the shortcut from [2] and scroll it
4. Press Esc to unfocus documentation tool window and focus completion popup

Comment: Thanks for posting the bug and a workaround Konstantin. Having to rely on the documentation tool window open isn't exactly ideal, but I think that it works well enough for now.